# Sending image within a form to a php server

Tags: php, html, forms

Im trying to upload a file through a form to my php server and then display the name of the file. ATM I'm getting an error when I'm trying to submit the form:
Objekt was not found! Error 404

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
        <input type="file" name="file" size="35">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
    </body>
</html>

<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
    if(isset($_FILES["file"])){
        $file = $_FILES["file"];
        echo("File: ".$file);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to upload/do any operation on same file then remove `action` from form. then change your code as below to echo file name

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input type="file" name="file" size="35">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
    </body>
</html>

<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    if(isset($_FILES["file"])){
        $file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        echo "File: ".$file;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: its not same file, php and html are seperated

Comment: so php file name is `upload.php`?